# Google data visualization stacked bar charts using two data sets

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, data-visualization

I am using google datavisualization charts. I have a datatable with 2 columns and 4 rows. I need to display this data into a single stacked bar chart as shown below
[image]

Sample of my data :

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'name');
data.addColumn('number', 'count');
data.addRows([
    ['abc', 321],
    ['def', 163],
    ['ghi', 125],
    ['jkl', 197]
]);
```

I have tried using column chart and bar chart by enabling isStacked:true , but no luck. 
Is there a way to display the data in a single stacked chart as shown in the image. I don't mind whether it is a bar chart or column chart.

I would appreciate if someone can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that right now there is nothing linking the different columns together, so that there is no reason for them to be stacked on top of each other.

You need to have each of the elements share a common element, like the date. Next, you need to add a separate column for each of the different 'name' fields. Finally, when adding your values, add them only to the column index that matches the (name, value) pair.

```
data.addColumn('number', 'irrelevant');
data.addColumn('number', 'abc');
data.addColumn('number', 'def');
data.addColumn('number', 'ghi');
data.addColumn('number', 'jkl');
data.addColumn('number', 'mno');
data.addRows([
    [0, 321, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 163, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 125, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 452, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 825]
]);
```

This sort of thing is annoying to do by hand, so in my chart system I iterate through a list of all the different groupings (or 'name's in your case) and keep track of each index so I know which element of the individual row to specify.

Here's a small sample from my code so you can get the right idea:

```
GoogleDataTable.addColumn('number', 'Age');

var GroupIndex = 0;
var DateIndex = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < RawJSON.length; i++) {
    //If the groupkey is not in the group array yet.
    if (GroupArray.indexOf(RawJSON[i][GroupKey]) == -1) {
        GroupArray[GroupIndex] = RawJSON[i][GroupKey];
        GroupIndex++;
        GoogleDataTable.addColumn('number', RawJSON[i][GroupKey]);
    }
    //If the timeslice is not yet in the Date array.
    if (DateArray.indexOf(RawJSON[i]["Age"]) == -1) {
        DateArray[DateIndex] = RawJSON[i]['Age'];
        DateIndex++;
    }
}
```

then later

```
var groupIndex = GroupArray.indexOf(RawJSON[i][GroupKey]) + 1;
for (var j = 1; j <= GroupIndex; j++) {
    if (j == groupIndex) {
       RowArray[insertIndex][groupIndex] = RawJSON[i]['Value'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type" error. It is because the name field is "string" data type. In Bar charts or Column charts only the first column name should be string data type and the remaining columns must be numbers. But in my case I have 2 columns one with string data type and other with number type. Is there any other way around ?

Comment: I totally revamped my answer for you.